# Error: Multiplicity Constraint Violated on db.SaveChanges?

Tags: sql, wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, constraints

I a am new to entity framework. I have created project with Entity Model. When i am trying to add item in to the table it gives error "Multiplicity Constraint violated" Any idea?

ID From Table MAPPER is FK in MAPS table.

In Code Behind:

```
private Mapper mMapper;
    if (mMapper.Id == 0)
                        db.Mappers.Add(mMapper);
                        db.SaveChanges();

 public partial class Mapper
    {
        public Mapper()
        {
            this.Maps = new HashSet<Map>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string RecordDelimiter { get; set; }
        public string ValueDelimiter { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ColumnDescriptionRow { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FirstRowOfData { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IgnoreThisRecord { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> ExplodePartQuantity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IgnoreImportingErrors { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AngleMappingLeadingEdgeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AngleMappingTrailingEdgeId { get; set; }
        public string ValueWrapper { get; set; }
        public string ValueWrapperDelimiter { get; set; }

        public virtual AngleMapping AngleMapping { get; set; }
        public virtual AngleMapping AngleMapping1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Map> Maps { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a model check triggered by using the model, not by the data itself. Is `Map.MapperId` a nullable column in the database?

Comment: imho your Mapper has a reference to a Map that is not attached to the context.

Comment: yes @GertArnold Map.MapperID is nullable so shall i need to remove it?

Comment: @tschmit007 what do you mean? i am not getting you please will you clarify little more and could you solve my problem?

Comment: No, it means that the multiplicity can be 0..1, so there is no mismatch between the database and your model. It must be something else. Does `mMapper` have a `Map`?

Comment: please check i have edited my post

Comment: What I mean is that the mMapper you are trying to a should have mMapper.Map != null. And I think that mMapper.Map is not in the context, so EF is trying to insert it in the db and fails because of multiplicity constraint on Map.

Comment: so how to resolve this issue? please tell me..!